# How can i split the text into two columns in same length using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have used the code of below reference link for reading simulation.

https://jsfiddle.net/g9zsa86n/

I have created a box by using `<div id="sim"></div>`. it is working good, but now i have situated to change this into 2 columns in same length.

**Q1:** how to split the text into 2 columns?

**Q2:** And the reading cursor will travel down the column on the left, 
then down the column on the right.

**For example:**

If have entered around 100 words into the box, it will shows first 2 lines in first column, next 2 lines in 2nd column. After read these 4 lines, cursor should travel next 2 lines of 1st column, next 2 lines of 2nd column with autoscroll-x, autoscroll-y.

if it is possible to change, could someone help me?

Comment: Dude you should post all these as an answer and make some rep points :)

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with just CSS 3. The [Multi column layout module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/) defines column-count. Set it to 2 and it will A1. split the div in 2 and A2. have your cursor behave as expected.

https://jsfiddle.net/g9zsa86n/3/

```
#sim{
    column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
}
```

It's fairly [well supported across browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=column). If you use something like [compass](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/columns/) to write your css, it will actually be maintainable.

PS And as 
[humble.rumble commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30638723/how-can-i-split-the-text-into-two-columns-in-same-length-using-javascript/#comment-49342243), to support ye olde browsers you can fallback to modernizer with a [shim](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#css-layout-modules).